# Generate a directed random graph using Erdős–Rényi model from a real directed graph

Tags: graph, probability, networkx, directed-graph, degrees

I'm trying to understand how to correctly generate a directed random graph based on **Erdős–Rényi model**. I have looked at `erdos_renyi_graph` function on [network x](https://networkx.github.io/).
I have set as n parameter the number of nodes of my real network (5317) then for p i have calculated:

```
p = (< k_in > + < k_out >)/(n-1) = (78,302 )/(5317-1) = 0, 014729496
```

I have calculated the average degree as the sum of in_degree and out_degree.

Applying this probability it has generated a random graph with 5317 nodes and 415.727 edges. Many more edges than my real network(207.167 edges).

Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it's correct, cause the average degree(as sum of `k_in` and `k_out`) is reasonably higher than indegree and outdegree. So if you treat the graph as directed in the `Erdős–Rényi` model you should have something like `average degree/2` because for each edge, there are two vertexes associated to it. So each edge adds two degrees to the graph, according to the **degree sum formula**:

[image: indegree+outdegree formula]

That's the reason of diving by 2 the result. So in this circumstance it will generate a random graph with around the same number of edges of your real graph.